# Wrong API response type, user search

Tags: bug, chat, search

#### Location

- Page: https://chat.stackexchange.com/search
- Field: «when said by» `[name=user]#user`

When no result is found, the API responds with the plain text «No records.»
Then JavaScript code tried to parse that text as JSON, with obvious fail.

[image: Plain text response and JSON.parse error]

As result, autofill looks like infinite loading, because the `JSON.parse` exception is uncaught.

[image: Infinite loading]